# text-overflow: ellipsis ignoring right padding on mobile

Tags: ios, css, mobile

I have a div styled to truncate centered text with an ellipsis, with some padding on each side. It works when using a desktop browser, but on iPad the text seems to ignore the right padding and becomes centered incorrectly.

I'm using this for the styling:

```
div {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 120px;
    padding: 0 38px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}
```

An example can be seen here. View on iPad to see the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/35Lyk9yp/

I'm thinking this might be some bug with the mobile browsers? It didn't work on iOS Safari or Chrome, but it's ok on Windows Safari and Chrome and Firefox. Is there a simple workaround for it?

Edit:

I found a workaround by using an inner `div` with the content that I used to do the ellipsis, and then used the outer `div` to set the padding. If there is a way around it with one element though, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get your code to work you need to have CSS `overflow`, `width` and `display`.

You are probably missing the `display`.

Comment: No, that wasn't it... I tried adding display and it made no difference. Also the example above was working as expected on the desktop browsers already.